# Rerun a co-ordinator job from the command line

Tags: oozie

My scheduler ran a oozie co-ordinator job successfully. I can see the co-ordinator ID in the web ui and from my command line I can also do

```
oozie job --oozie http://foo.com:11000/oozie/ -info 0119337-160219063120217-oozie-oozi-C
```

This prints a bunch of stuff on the command line regarding the previous run.

Now I want to run this on demand so I give the command

```
oozie job --oozie http://foo:11000/oozie/ -rerun 0119337-160219063120217-oozie-oozi-C
```

Now it gives an error

```
Error: Invalid options provided for rerun: date or action expected.
```

So I try

```
oozie job --oozie http://foo.com:11000/oozie/ -rerun 0119337-160219063120217-oozie-oozi-C -date "2016-03-14 00:00:00"

Error: E0302 : E0302: Invalid parameter [2016-03-14 00:00:00]
```

I also tried

```
oozie job --oozie http://vtqaana-clouderamgr01.dealer.ddc:11000/oozie/ -rerun 0119337-160219063120217-oozie-oozi-C -action 18
```

Now it says

```
Error: E1018 : E1018: Coord Job Rerun Error: part or all actions are not eligible to rerun!
```

So no matter what I do... oozie will not let me rerun my co-ordinator job.

Here is the screenshot of my job

[image]

I want to rerun it from the beginning using the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates specified in -date must be **UTC format**.
You need to pass date in following format :

```
$oozie job -rerun <coord_Job_id> [-nocleanup] [-refresh]
[-action 1, 3-4, 7-40] (-action or -date is required to rerun.)
[-date 2009-01-01T01:00Z::2009-05-31T23:59Z, 2009-11-10T01:00Z, 2009-12-31T22:00Z]
```

Please refer the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CoordinatorRerun.html) for more details.